# Docusign - Auto-Place tabs not show up on base64 document

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to auto-place multiple `signHere` tabs in one of my base64 documents where the length of the document is dynamic, based on a keyword `Signature`, but none of them are being attached. Here's my code snippet:

```kotlin
val base64String = <some_base64_string>

EnvelopeDefinition().apply {
    emailSubject = "..."
    emailBlurb = "..."
    documents = listOf(
        Document().apply {
            documentId = "1"
            name = "demo.pdf"
            documentBase64 = base64String
        }
    )
    recipients = listOf(
        Signer().apply {
            email = <email>
            name = <name>
            recipientId = "1"
            roleName = "Client"
            clientUserId = id
            val tabs = Tabs()
            tabs.signHereTabs = listOf(
                SignHere().apply {
                    anchorString = "Signature"
                    name = "signature-$id"
                    tabLabel = "sign-here-$id"
                }
            )
            this.tabs = tabs
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a template (roleName) but you also provide your own document and your own tabs.

The purpose of a template is to have a repetitive process where something is repeated. Either the documents or the tabs or the recipients.

Not sure what you're trying to do here, but either:

1. Don't use a template.
2. Have the tabs defined on the template.
3. Have the document in the template.

The way you have it won't work cause the tabs won't be applied to the new document.

For your tab code , try something like this:

```
sign_here1 = {
    anchorString = "Signature", anchorYOffset = "10", anchorUnits = "pixels",
    anchorXOffset = "20"}
```

Comment: Hi Inbar, thanks for your quick reply. I didn't realize `roleName` playing a part here. What i'm trying to do is providing my own document (length is dynamic, and no template involves), then let Docusign scan the document, finding the keyword, and auto-place tabs to those keywords

Comment: The document is generated on our web application and is sent to Docusign, so i'm not sure how it can fit into a template, also a template cannot be created without at least 1 document provided

Comment: are you using a template or are you not using a template?

Comment: i'm not using a template. My second comment is a question for the 3rd point `Have the document in the template` you suggested, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Remove "roleName = "Client" from your code then

Comment: Put some updated code for you in the answer

Comment: Please double-check your document has the word "Signature" in it, capitalization must be identical for it to be found!

Comment: I think Auto-place functionality is working fine overall, found out that when I copy paste the english content from the pdf into another editor it turns into gibberish that's probably why `anchorstring` cannot be placed properly through the document. I'll accept your original answer